# unable to view APP PROFILE PAGE .... "The page you requested was not found"

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-canvas

Problem App: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=299226733441387

For some reason I am unable to view any NEW ...App Profile Pages... after I create a basic page tab app! 
When I click on the   "View App Profile Page"  I get the error "The page you requested was not found"

Also, if I use the canvas app section too, when I click on "View App Profile Page" it directs the browsert to the canvas page.

Previous apps created are NOT affected by this error!

Any one have any ideas on what this could be? Or how to resolve the error?

Comment: I received the same error. It's straight forward to just create a new app, somehow that works, so it's probably a Facebook-related issue, nothing we can do.

Comment: In the new apps we are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the same thread, the workaround is to use this URL:

http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=[APP-ID]&pages=1

Replace [APP-ID] with yours, and it should work.

Comment: This still works and is currently the only way to do it, if the "View App Profile Page" link is missing ...

Answer (score 2):

I were struggling with same issue.I have read & found that fb is removing app profile page on 1st of Feb 2012.

So the process is to get app profile page is:-

> Go to app setting->Advance tab->Contact info->Add page.

I have attached a snap shot.I hope that will help you guys.

Thanks
[image]